# How can I swap the Cmd + Option keys on my external keyboard when using Ulysses for iPad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, ipados

I have an external Bluetooth keyboard, the Filco Majestouch MINILA Air.

I'd like to use it to write documents in Ulysses on my iPad Pro, but it's confusing because the Option and Cmd keys are in the wrong position. They need to be swapped.

I haven't been able to find a global iPad setting which can do this even though there does seem to be a lot of options for accessibility.

The keyboard has dipswitches for swapping all sorts of things, but they didn't include one for this pretty obvious need!

The app I use for ssh, Blink, allows for remapping of all the special keys, but I couldn't find anything in Ulysses for this.

**tl;dr** is there a way to swap Cmd and Option on iPadOS generally or even just in Ulysses?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for iOS.  Have you asked the Ulysses folks?

Comment: I haven't, that's probably next on my list, I figured if nothing else documenting the current status here was valuable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searched around on this because I was looking at a keyboard where this was the main flaw and came across your question. Then just looked in System Settings, and not sure when they added it, but the option to swap modifier keys is there now! It's under General -> Keyboard -> Hardware Keyboard.

Comment: Yes Apple finally fixed it! It makes the iPad so much more useful.